# Should I remove the files marked with yellow?

Tags: wcf, web-services, xsd

I have a WCF service in my console project. If I expand the service reference in the project node, you will find some files marked with yellow ! triangle sign.

[image: 1]

For example: BOERPI.disco, BOERPI1.xsd and BOERPI2.xsd in the image file. If I double click it, it gave me the warning such as:

[image: 2]

Why it happened? Should I remove them?

Also please look t the image, there are files of configuration.svcinfo and configuration91.svcinfo. They don't have yellow mark. Should I delete one of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those files are automatically generated by the Visual Studio *Add Service Reference* wizard. You shouldn't manually edit/delete those files. The only file that really matters is the `Reference.cs` (or .vb as appropriate) contained under the `Reference.svcmap` node. That file contains the actual C# (or VB) service proxy implementation classes.

You can regenerate the `BOERPIServiceReference` node by right clicking on that item in Solution Explorer and selecting the *Update Service Reference* option. If Visual Studio won't let you do that, then get the URL (or file path) to the service WSDL, delete the current service reference and go through the *Add Service Reference* wizard again using the **identical** service reference name as the current reference.

Comment: OOPS, I delete these files before your posting. Does it matter for the application?

Comment: Probably not, since they're used by Visual Studio and not by your application. Deleting the `Reference.cs` file, on the other hand, will cause your project to fail to build.